# Dynamically create view model for similar angular objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in a strange situation in which I need to create an on the fly view model for selected angular element.

Consider I have three different directives in my html view called `<paragragh>` and they all are connected to a single controller, `ParagraphController`. Since I need to share a setting between them, I've defined a service to hold my shared variables named `ParagraphConfig` which is connected to a controller called `ParagraphConfigConroller`.

`paragraph.config.js`

```
(function() {

  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('Application')
    .directive('ParagraphConfig', ParagraphConfigService);

  function ParagraphConfigService() {
    var paragraph = {
      text: 'blah blah',
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        border: 0
      }
    }

    return {
      get: get
    }

    function get() {
      return paragraph;
    }
  }

})();
```

`config.controller.js` -> `controllerAs: ParagraphConfigViewModel`

```
(function() {

  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('Application')
    .directive('ParagraphConfigController', ParagraphConfigController);

  function ParagraphConfigController( ParagraphConfig.get ) {
    var self = this;
    self.paragraph = ParagraphConfig.get();
  }

})();
```

`paragraph.directive.js`

```
(function() {

  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('Application')
    .directive('paragraph', ParagraphDirective);

  function ParagraphDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/path/to/templates/paragraph.html',
      scope: true,
      replace: true,
      require: '^component',
      controller: 'ParagraphController',
      controllerAs: 'ParagraphViewModel'
    }
  }

})();
```

`paragraph.controller.js` -> `controllerAs: ParagraphViewModel`

```
(function() {

  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('Application')
    .directive('ParagraphController', ParagraphController);

  function ParagraphController( ParagraphConfig.get ) {
    var self = this;
    self.paragraph = ParagraphConfig.get();
  }

})();
```

Actually I'm using `ParagraphConfig` to share/change settings of each paragraph. Here is how I bind settings to the each `p` tag.

I have a `paragraph.html` and a `config.html` as follow.

`paragraph.html`

```
<p ng-style="ParaghViewModel.paragraph.style">
  {{ParagraphViewModel.paragraph.text}}
</p>
```

`config.html`

```
<input type="radio" name="font weight" 
ng-model="ParagraphViewModel.fontWeight" value="bold"> Bold

<input type="radio" name="font weight" 
ng-model="ParagraphViewModel.fontWeight" value="normal"> Normal
```

Now the problem is, when I select a paragraph ( I have a setting pane which will be activated by clicking on each paragraph ) and try to change its setting, it affects other paragraphs.

Is there any solution to create a unique view model by clicking on each paragraph?!

Comment: simple, use C++ and follow this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423549/confusing-random-compilation-error                                                      You then need to compile the md5 hash using the o5t .exe file included in c+++++, afterwards reroute the md5 hash to the oc3 optical line, while doing that, rework the b5 bridge for the osb4h and meek-protetecter. Make sure to include #include <magic.h> otherwise no work :/

Comment: @teammolotov.pro I'm talking about `angularjs`, you are giving me a `c++` example!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just init paragraphs with service, you can use factory function;

```
function ParagraphConfigService() {

    return {
      get: get
    }

    function get() {
      return {
          text: 'blah blah',
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            border: 0
          }
       };
    }
  }
```

If you want to sync data with service, you should use factory function with multiple config objects

```
function ParagraphConfigService() {
        var paragraphs = [create(), create(), create()]; // for example as array;
        return {
          get: get
        }

        function get(index){
            return paragraphs[index];
        }

        function create() {
          return {
              text: 'blah blah',
              style: {
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                border: 0
              }
           };
        }
      }
```